# Java - Tic Tac Toe Win Condition

Tags: java

I am trying to make it so that when a player has 3 X's or O's in a row, that character is returned. I am not allowed to use arrays or cells, just string methods and conditionals. My problem is, I have no clue how to show when the diagonals or the vertical win conditions are met, just when the horizontal is. Also, I am not sure how to represent a cats game.

Here is what I have so far:

```
String row1 = " | | ";
String row2 = " | | ";
String row3 = " | | ";
String filler = "-----";

public String WinnerOrTie(){ 
        if (row1 == "O|O|O") {
           return "O";
        }
        else if (row2 == "O|O|O"){
            return "O";
        }
        else if (row3 == "O|O|O"){
            return "O";
        }

        if (row1 == "X|X|X") {
            return "X";
        }
        else if (row2 == "X|X|X"){
            return "X";
        }
        else if (row3 == "X|X|X"){
            return "X";
        }
```

Comment: You need to encode the board in an appropriate structure, for example an array.

Comment: You can't compare strings with ==. You need to use String#equals().

Answer (score 1):

If you are not allowed to use arrays, then you're going to have to hard-code everything. For example:

```
if (row1.charAt(0) == 'O' && row2.charAt(0) == 'O' && row3.charAt(0) == 'O')
{
    return "O";
}
```

This code checks the far left column, but you should be able to use the same method to check the other columns and the diagonals.

Comment: Besides rows, don't forget that you have verticals and diagonals to check.  That's what the code above does, checks one vertical.

Answer (score 0):

A simple answer since your stuck trying to write `WinnerOrTie` method try to see what `strings` are made up of (chars?). Okay, if that's the case use loops to go over the board and simply check for `winning conditions` if `not found` you have a `stale mate`. Since you said no array, or cells you have so little to do. Please keep in mind `diagnol` wins also. To check for that `hint` think of the middle position.

@Oakley's answer's correct, I just wrote this while he answered. So, feel free to expand.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an assignment. I will lead you to water on this one. There is something called AND and OR operators. They are && for AND and || for OR.

For instance in a philosophical logic exercise, "If I have bought apples AND bananas, then buy a basket." So, if I have bought apples but no bananas, then I won't buy a basket. If I have bought bananas but no apples, then I won't buy the basket. Only when I have bought both apples and bananas, then I would buy a basket. Both statements have to be true for an AND condition.

Another example, "If I have bought apples OR bananas, then buy a basket." If I have bought either apples or bananas, then I would buy a basket. If I have bought both, I would buy a basket. If I didn't by neither, I would not buy a basket.

The code for that will look like this: (assume scanner is defined as input and this is in main. -> are tabs (admins help))

```
System.out.print("Input the apples and bananas bought today to see if you need a basket.\n");
int applesBought = input.nextInt();
int bananasBought = input.nextInt();
//for an AND operator
if(applesBought > 0 && bananasBought > 0) //both conditions must be true
-> System.out.print("Buy a basket.\n")
else
-> System.out.print("Don't buy a basket.\n")

//for an OR operator
if(applesBought > 0 || bananasBought > 0) //only 1 of the conditions must be true
-> System.out.print("Buy a basket.\n")
else
-> System.out.print("Don't buy a basket.\n")
```

Depending on your sanity and if your IDE allows it, you can have a lot of AND and OR statements, like:

```
if(a == b && c == d && e == f && ... && y == z)
if(a == b || c == d || e == f || ... || y == z)
```

Looking at your code, you will may have to write a lot of the kinds of statements above, but you can use everything I mentioned with strings also. Good luck and leave a comment if you have questions.

Answer (score 0):

```
String row1 = " | | ";
String row2 = " | | ";
String row3 = " | | ";
String filler = "-----";

public String WinnerOrTie()
{ 
        if (row1 == "O|O|O") {
           return "O";
        }
        else if (row2 == "O|O|O"){
            return "O";
        }
        else if (row3 == "O|O|O"){
            return "O";
        }

        if (row1 == "X|X|X") {
            return "X";
        }
        else if (row2 == "X|X|X"){
            return "X";
        }
        else if (row3 == "X|X|X"){
            return "X";
        }
        else if (row1.charAt(0) == "O" && row2.charAt(0) == "O" && row3.charAt(0) == "O")
        {
             return "O";
        }
        else if (row1.charAt(2) == "O" && row2.charAt(2) == "O" && row3.charAt(2) == "O")
        {
             return "O";
        }
        else if (row1.charAt(4) == "O" && row2.charAt(4) == "O" && row3.charAt(4) == "O")
        {
            return "O";
        }
        else if (row1.charAt(0) == "O" && row2.charAt(2) == "O" && row3.charAt(4) == "O")
        {
            return "O";
        }
        else if (row1.charAt(4) == "O" && row2.charAt(2) == "O" && row3.charAt(0) == "O")
        {
            return "O";
        }


        else if (row1.charAt(0) == "X" && row2.charAt(0) == "X" && row3.charAt(0) == "X")
        {
            return "X";
        }
        else if (row1.charAt(2) == "X" && row2.charAt(2) == "X" && row3.charAt(2) == "X")
        {
            return "X";
        }
        else if (row1.charAt(4) == "X" && row2.charAt(4) == "X" && row3.charAt(4) == "X")
        {
            return "X";
        }
        else if (row1.charAt(0) == "X" && row2.charAt(2) == "X" && row3.charAt(4) == "X")
        {
            return "X";
        }
        else if (row1.charAt(4) == "X" && row2.charAt(2) == "X" && row3.charAt(0) == "X")
        {
            return "X";
        }
}
```

Hope this Code Works!!

Comment: `row2.charAt(0) == "2"`?

Comment: Sorry made a type error there. And I have edited it. Thanks for the noting it!!

Comment: Please read [How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and update your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are **not** allowed to use methods, pick an answer that already mentioned before since it will be 'hard coded'.
If you can use methods, you can do something like this

```
public String WinnerOrTie() 
{
    if (rowsFilledWith(row1,row2,row3, 'X'))
        return "X";
    
    if (rowsFilledWith(row1,row2,row3, 'O'))
        return "O";
    
    return "TIE";
}


private boolean rowsFilledWith(String row1,String row2,String row3, char letter) 
{
    return rowFilledWith(row1,letter) || rowFilledWith(row2,letter) || rowFilledWith(row3,letter);
}

private boolean rowFilledWith(String row,char letter)
{
    return row.charAt(0) == letter && row.charAt(2) == letter && row.charAt(4) == letter;
}
```

Then you can improvise the other conditions (columns and diagonials). For example,

```
private static boolean columnFilledWith(String row1,String row2,String row3,char letter)
{
    return row1.charAt(0) == letter && row2.charAt(0) == letter && row3.charAt(0) == letter;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
public String WinnerOrTie() {
    String all =
          "|" + row1.charAt(0) + row1.charAt(2) + row1.charAt(4)
        + "|" + row2.charAt(0) + row2.charAt(2) + row2.charAt(4)
        + "|" + row3.charAt(0) + row3.charAt(2) + row3.charAt(4)
        + "|" + row1.charAt(0) + row2.charAt(0) + row3.charAt(0)
        + "|" + row1.charAt(2) + row2.charAt(2) + row3.charAt(2)
        + "|" + row1.charAt(4) + row2.charAt(4) + row3.charAt(4)
        + "|" + row1.charAt(0) + row2.charAt(2) + row3.charAt(4)
        + "|" + row1.charAt(4) + row2.charAt(2) + row3.charAt(0);
    return all.contains("OOO") ? "O" : all.contains("XXX") ? "X" : "Tie";
}
```